# Placing Manipulate controls in multiple columns

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I have a `Manipulate` construct with a square `Graphic` on the left side and all the controls placed on the right side. There are so many (and also pretty large) control items, however, that they take up about double the vertical space of the graphic.

Is there a simple way to place the controls into two seperate columns (like in the sketch below)?

```
 _________
|         | Control 1 | Control 4
| Graphic | Control 2 | Control 5
|_________| Control 3 | Control 6
```

I could do something similar using `Item` and `Grid`, but as far as I know, in such a construct the default control syntax wouldn't work and I'd have to re-program all the controls with `Dynamic`. It seems `ControlPlacement` also does not support multiple columns.

**Edit:** To be clear: I'm trying to find a solution that preserves as much of `Manipulate`'s properties as possible, i.e. things like alignment, labeling and using default control types.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am not sure why you can't just use Grid?

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -lim, lim}],
 Grid[{
   {Control[{{lim, Pi, "limit"}, Pi/10, 2 Pi, Pi/10, 
      ImageSize -> Tiny}], Button["A", ImageSize -> 100]},
   {Button["B", ImageSize -> 100], Button["C", ImageSize -> 100]},
   {Button["D", ImageSize -> 100], Button["E", ImageSize -> 100]}
   }, Frame -> All],
 ControlPlacement -> Right
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I already know it can be done to a certain extent like this. I'm basically looking for some solution that fully preserves the `Manipulate` desing (along with alignment of the labels and controls) and the default control types, such as displaying a color slider automatically when writing something like `{{textcolor, Orange, "Text color"}, Orange}`.

Comment: @einbandi, this answer already covers those  requirements: all you need is to put your `Manipulate` controls inside `Control`. You don't lose any feature of `Manipulate`. That is, `Control[{{textcolor, Orange, "Text color"}, Orange}]` automatically uses `ColorSlider`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was totally missing the `Control` command there. I'll see then if I can achieve optically pleasing results with that