# How can I mimic this beautiful layout for a table?

Tags: output-formatting, style

I was looking for new ideas to display my data, when I found this beautiful layout in a video lecture ([Wolfram U: Visualisation des données avec le Wolfram Language - Partie 2](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?sx=neural%20networks&c=105&ob=title&o=ASC&v=3068&p=33&&disp=list)).

[image]

I would like to mimic that layout, for example

[image]

I wonder if this was obtained by a custom code combining Panel[], Column[], Row[], and Button[], or if there is a simpler command to achieve these types of layouts in Mathematica.

Comment: There are also few questions on this site about how arrange layouts. For example [placing-manipulate-controls-in-multiple-columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14781/placing-manipulate-controls-in-multiple-columns)  and [manipulate-delimiter-between-control-and-content](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250487/manipulate-delimiter-between-control-and-content)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would just use Grid for everything. Maybe with combination of Panel and Row if needed.

You setup each row of the grid, then add them. Each row itself in turn can be a Grid, and so on. Basically you can setup any complicated structure you want by nesting Grids.

Here is a quick one to illustrate. Button and slide do nothing in this, just for display, Only the time runs. You can control the background color and the alignment of each entry in the Grid also.

[image]

Code

```
DynamicModule[{e0, e1, e2, e3, e4, sol, angle, bob, r, time = 0, 
  animationRate = 1, k},
 
 e0 = Row[{" My nice demo "}];
 e1 = Grid[{{Trigger[Dynamic[time], {0, Infinity, 0.01},
      animationRate,
      AppearanceElements -> {"PlayPauseButton", "ResetButton"}],
     Style["time (sec)", 10], Dynamic[NumberForm[time, {3, 2}]]}}, 
   Spacings -> {1, 1}];
 e2 = Row[{Dynamic@
     Show[Graphics[{{Dashed, Gray, Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}, {Red, Thick, 
         Line[{{0, 0}, bob}]}, {Blue, PointSize[0.1], Point[bob]}}, 
       ImagePadding -> 10], ImageSize -> 300]}];
 e3 = Control[{{k, 1, "k"}, 1, 20, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}];
 e4 = Button[Text@Style["run", 12], ImageSize -> {50, 40}];
 
 Dynamic@Grid[{ 
    {e0},
    {Grid[{{e2, Grid[{{e1}, {e3}}, FrameStyle -> LightGray]}}, 
      Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> LightGray]},
    {e4}
    },
   Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> LightGray, Spacings -> {1, 1},
   Alignment -> {Left, Left, {{3, 1} -> Right}},
   Background -> {None, 
     None, {{1, 1} -> LightGray, {3, 1} -> LightGray}}],
 
 Initialization :> (sol := 
    First@NDSolve[{y''[t] + 0.1 y'[t] + Sin[y[t]] == 1.5 Cos[t], 
       y[0] == Pi/4, y'[0] == 0}, y, {t, time, time + 1}, 
      Sequence@ndsolveOptions];
   bob := {Sin[(y /. sol)[time]], -Cos[(y /. sol)[time]]};
   ndsolveOptions = {MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
     Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
       Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 10};)]
```

I am sure there are many other ways to do this.